# Spring cloud does Turbine require Eureka or it's working with consul as well?

Tags: spring-cloud, consul, turbine

We are using **consul** for service discovery. We want to aggregates all circuit breakers stream with turbine.

Does Turbine requires Eureka for the discovery part or it's working as well with consul ?

I'm getting these errors :

```
com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Can't get a response from   http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/TURBINE
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbine doesn't work with consul yet: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/53

Comment: That wasn't obvious from the spring cloud documentation. Is it part of the Brixton roadmap or more likely another release? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I'd like it to land in Brixton.

Comment: This has been fixed. See [the new documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc#circuit-breaker-with-hystrix) for usage.